# Why does Excel translate `=10**-2` to `=0.1`?

Tags: excel, undefined-behavior, mathematical-expressions

Try pasting `=10**-2` into a cell in MS Excel. After pressing Enter, it turns it to `=0.1`. I can't seem to find any documentation for `**`, but it appears to be a pretty odd exponentiation-like operator that cannot be used in an Excel formula (e.g., `=A1**A2` is invalid`).

If this operator is not an exponentiation operator, what is it?

(N.B.: mathematically, 10<sup>-2</sup> = 0.01, not 0.1)

Comment: Why the close votes? I think this is a perfectly valid question: referencing an undocumented behaviour, defines a use case that can be replicated, explicitly asks a question about that behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

** is the same as E

=4E3 == 4**3 == 4000

Comment: No because `.1` * `.1` would be `0.01`, not `0.1`

Comment: not the same as ^ or power. this is not an operator, which is what is confusing. It is functionally equivalent to typing the letter "E" between two numbers.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, this matches F.J.'s examples exactly. I think Roger nailed it. This is an alternative entry method for scientific notation.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was much more eloquent than my explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that `A**B` shifts the decimal point of `A` to the right by `B` positions, or mathematically `A**B` is equivalent to `A*(10^B)`.

This is basically a scientific notation shorthand, so `1.23**-2` would show up as `1.23E-02` in the cell, so not only does it perform the shifting as described above but it will change that cell's category to 'Scientific'.  *Note that this is only the case if you enter the value into the cell without a leading* `=`*, so* `=1.23**-2` *would keep the current default for the cell and display* `0.0123`.

In the case of `10**-2`, the decimal point is being shifted to the left by 2 positions (since `B` is negative), resulting in 0.1.

Here are a few examples:

```
1**-2 => 0.01
1.2**2 => 120
.5**1 => 5
```

Comment: And it only works with a literal. He's right you can't do=A1**A2.

Comment: For the life of me I can't find where this operator is documented though.

Comment: Yeah I have been looking for it in documentation as well, no luck yet.